# Cannot update APT list: "repository no longer has a Release file"

Tags: debian, apt

I cannot run `apt-get update` as I encounter the following error:

```
# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian testing InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security testing/updates InRelease
Err:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security testing/updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.92.204 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security testing/updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Repository 'http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian testing InRelease' changed its 'Codename' value from 'buster' to 'bullseye'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
```

So there are two error messages here:

1. The repository no longer has a Release file, which is weird. I checked at http://security-cdn.debian.org/debian-security/zzz-dists/testing/updates/ ant it looks like the Release file is there. Am I looking in the wrong place or is there something else happening?
2. The repository changed its name from `buster` to `bullseye` and that this "must be accepted explicitly" (I saw this *once* today; it wasn't there when I opened the question and it does not appear anymore). This isn't really surprising, but I didn't expect it to be a problem if I'm tracking the repository as `testing` instead of the release name.

What can I do? APT is telling me to read the `apt-secure(8)`, but it either does not have the information I need or I cannot understand it.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Change `testing/updates` to `testing-security` in your `sources.list` to match http://security-cdn.debian.org/debian-security/dists/testing-security/

Then run `apt update` instead of `apt-get update` to interactively accept the various changes.

According to this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/ca2fvn/debian_testing_fails_to_upgrade_now/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) this repository name change was introduced in release 10.

Comment: This answer seems to be the only one that answers the actual question, although the other answers are still interesting.

Comment: I've wondered about `apt` vs `apt-get` for a long time now. This caused me to finally look it up. [`apt` is the preferred way to do package management for end-users.](https://itsfoss.com/apt-vs-apt-get-difference/)

Comment: This solves the issue. In addition, the answer to my other question is: the link I posted is correct; no Release file is missing. But the file says "`buster`". I'm guessing it was deprecated a while ago and I missed the announcement.

Comment: The link you posted does exist indeed, but the `zzz-dists` part in the URL is unusual. It looks like a folder I would rename to push it down a file list. I wasn't aware of the `testing/updates` renaming until I faced the same issue as you did. It is mentioned by [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting): _If you are tracking testing or the next-stable code name, you should always have a corresponding deb http://security.debian.org <"testing" or codename>-security main line in your /etc/apt/sources.list_ .

Comment: To be precise it shoud be "Change testing/updates to testing-security/updates ..."

Comment: This is not what the various links posted say, nor what I have in place in my `sources.list`. So I checked and using `testing-security/updates` does not raise any kind of error. Hashing the corresponding files in `/var/lib/apt/lists` yields the same values, so there are multiple ways of collecting the same package list.

Comment: So using `/updates` is unnecessary because the result is the same? Both `stable-security/updates` and `stable-security` were working for me. You did not mention @user1708042 but I guess you replied to his comment.

Comment: The `/updates` part is not a keyword or anything like an option, but really a part of the directory hierarchy on the package servers. The reason it doesn't matter is that it is a symlink to its parent directory (see `http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stable-security/` and try clicking multiple times on the `updates` directory). I couldn't find any document explaining the purpose, it could be for backward compatibility, but this position in the apt line is normally expecting a Suites name according to the `sources.list` manpage.

Answer (score 25):

If you're upgrading from testing to buster, also be sure to run

`apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change`

If not, `apt-get update` won't let you update with Buster and will spit out messages like these:

> N: Repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease' changed its 'Version' value from '' to '10.0'
>
> E: Repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'testing' to 'stable'
>
> N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
>
> N: Repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease' changed its 'Version' value from '' to '10'
>
> E: Repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'testing' to 'stable'
>   N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.

Answer (score 13):

According to [Debian Project News published 1st of July,](https://www.debian.org/News/weekly/2019/01/) Debian 10 "Buster" was scheduled to transition from *testing* to *stable* on 2019-07-06.

It looks like the transition was in fact performed as scheduled, and so the *testing* distribution should now be catching up witn *unstable*, to eventually become Debian 11 "Bullseye". You might be experiencing some temporary side effects because of this transition of the Debian mirrors.

If you want to stay with Debian 10 "Buster", now would be a good time to switch your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to use the release name `buster` instead of `testing`.

Otherwise, you'll soon be getting the raw bleeding-edge stuff from *unstable*, and you might accidentally get a partial upgrade to proto-"Bullseye".

Also, this is a reminder for anyone using the word `stable` in their `/etc/apt/sources.list` to consider whether to change it to `stretch` and stay with the old version, or [read the Release Notes](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/releasenotes) and perform the recommended upgrade steps.

Comment: What would I have to do if I want to keep using the Testing branch? What should my sources.list say? Thanks!

Comment: Before 2019-07-06, *testing* meant Debian 10; now it means Debian 11. If you want to stay with Debian 10 you've been using so far, you should change the word `testing` in your `sources.list` to `buster` **right now**. On the other hand, if you actually want to be in the vanguard of the Debian 11 sprint, don't change anything. Perhaps wait a week or two for the worst of the storm to pass, monitor the appropriate Debian mailing lists, then run `apt full-upgrade` and see what happens. If something gets broken, make nice bug reports. You'll be testing Debian 11 while it starts to take shape!

Comment: PS: apparently there's something I missed in the error message yesterday or that's new. I'll check in the logs.

Comment: Nope. This is definitely new. I was aware of the transition. In fact, this is why I attempted to upgrade yesterday. To the best of my knowledge `testing` just came out of freeze and I wanted to update. So what is APT telling me? How do I "explicitly accept" the new codename of the distribution? I don't remember ever doing this before.

Comment: The codename of `testing` has changed from `buster` to `bullseye` to reflect the Debian 10 -> 11 transition, and that codename is included in the Release files. Looks like your version of `apt` is smart enough to block accidental upgrades from `buster` to `bullseye`. The priority of the Debian Project is likely in getting the new `stable` out and fixing any issues on it, so `testing` might be slightly broken for a few days until they get to creating the new APT keys for the new `testing` release. You may have to manually update the `debian-archive-keyring` pkg once a new one is released.

Comment: [Once a version 2019.2 or greater of `debian-archive-keyring` is released](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=debian-archive-keyring) (which has not happened yet!) and includes the new public keys for `bullseye`, you'll probably have to download it manually and install it with `dpkg -i <package.deb>`. After installing that, `apt` should be able to verify the packages of the new `bullseye` release and allow you to proceed with an `apt full-upgrade` to the next generation of *testing*.

Answer (score 6):

Run `apt update` and accept changes (type y each time when asked). It will made all required changes.

Comment: This works for those who want to remain with "buster release" which became stable.