# Upgrading Debian 9 Stretch to Debain 10 Buster

Tags: debian, upgrade, dist-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my Debian 9 to Debian 10.

I have changed my sources.list to following

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
```

Now whenever I am performing `apt update` I am getting following error

```
E: The repository 'http://build.openvpn.net/debian/openvpn/stable buster Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have already checked [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/528751/cannot-update-apt-list-repository-no-longer-has-a-release-file) post which talks about using testing repository. However, now that it is [officially](https://www.debian.org/News/2019/20190706) released, it should upgrade properly right? Am I missing something?

Comment: There appears to be an OpenVPN repository which most likely resides in a file under `sources.list.d`?

Comment: @Panki, Ahh, I missed the opvenvpn part. I just [checked](http://build.openvpn.net/debian/openvpn/stable/dists/). Openvpn had not released their build for buster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`build.openvpn.net`](https://build.openvpn.net/debian/openvpn/stable/dists/) repository accept only the following Debian codenames :

```
wheezy
jessie
stretch
```

Check your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` then disable the openvpn repository. The package `openvpn` can be installed from Debian repository later:

```
sudo apt install openvpn
```