# Linux Mint : Cannot do apt-get update

Tags: linux-mint, apt, proxy

I'm using the Linux Mint inside a proxy. I already configured the proxy settings in `/etc/environment` for the whole system and I used this solution (https://askubuntu.com/questions/257290/configure-proxy-for-apt) to configure the apt proxy.

But, when I try to call  `sudo apt-get update` I get the following result:

```
Ign:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Err:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic Release            
  Redirection loop encountered
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease   
Ign:4 http://packages.linuxmint.com tessa InRelease                      
Err:5 http://packages.linuxmint.com tessa Release
  Redirection loop encountered
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease       
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease      
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://packages.linuxmint.com tessa Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I did some searches on internet but I didn't find the solution for this issue. Also, I remember that when I had to use the `curl` command I had to set the proxy and enable the use of cookies, otherwise I would get these "Redirection loop".

Please, what should I do to fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/528751/cannot-update-apt-list-repository-no-longer-has-a-release-file

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Acquire::http::Proxy "https://yourproxyaddress:proxyport";

instead of

Acquire::http::Proxy "http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport";