# Changes in Debian Buster package repositories

Tags: debian, repository

It seems Debian is making changes in the repositories.
I get the following when updating my apt cache:

```
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [39.1 kB]
Get:2 http://ftp.dk.debian.org/debian buster InRelease [118 kB] 
Reading package lists... Done
N: Repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease' changed its 'Version' value from '' to '10'
E: Repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'testing' to 'stable'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
N: Repository 'http://ftp.dk.debian.org/debian buster InRelease' changed its 'Version' value from '' to '10.0'
E: Repository 'http://ftp.dk.debian.org/debian buster InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'testing' to 'stable'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
```

Do I need to update my `.gpg` files in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`? Is so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to run `apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change` as the version/suite name changed with the release of Buster.

See this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/529056/332764

Comment: Nice, thanks :-)